# SQL Count rows in GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

The following query returns the following results:

```
SELECT sales.users_id, users.region
FROM sales
JOIN users ON ( sales.users_id = users.id )
GROUP BY sales.users_id

users_id, region
1,    IE
2,    UK
3,    UK
4,    UK
5,    AU
6,    AU
```

QUESTION:

How do I modify the above query to get the following results:

```
IE, 1
UK, 3
AU, 2
```

Which is the number of users who purchased per region.
Where the numbers in the second column correspond to the count of sales per region?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: The `group by` in your example query does not make any sense (and is actually invalid SQL for any DBMS other than MySQL)

Comment: @Martin: Must be mysql. Oracle would throw up.

Comment: Yes am using mysql - should have mentioned that in question!

Comment: Can there be more than one sale per user, and in that case, do you want the number of sales or the number of users?

Comment: @klas - sales (unique to each user) per region

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT users.region, count(*)
FROM sales
JOIN users ON ( sales.users_id = users.id )
GROUP BY users.region;
```